# "None" text gets displayed after execution of main menu in loop

Tags: python-2.7

[image]I want to know how to stop the display of word "None" after every mainmenu() in loop.

```
import time
import add
import sub
import mul
import div

def mainmenu():
    print 30 * "-" , "MENU" , 30 * "-"
    print "1. Add"
    print "2. Substraction"
    print "3. Multiplication"
    print "4. Division"
    print "5. SquareRoot"
    print "6. Exit"
    print 67 * "-"

    while True:
        try:
            print mainmenu()
            choice = raw_input("Enter your correct number [1-7]: ")
            if choice   == "1":
                firstNum=input ("\nPlease enter first number : ")
                secondNum=input("Please enter Second number: ")
                print "Answer is " , add.ad(firstNum,secondNum)
                time.sleep(3)
            elif choice == "2":
                firstNum=input ("\nPlease enter first number : ")
                secondNum=input("Please enter Second number: ")
                print "Answer is " ,sub.su(firstNum,secondNum)
                time.sleep(3)
            elif choice == "3":
                firstNum=input ("\nPlease enter first number : ")
                secondNum=input("Please enter Second number: ")
                print "Answer is ",mul.mu(firstNum,secondNum)
                time.sleep(3)
            elif choice == "4":
                firstNum=input ("\nPlease enter first number : ")
                secondNum=input("Please enter Second number: ")
                print "Answer is " ,div.di(firstNum,secondNum)
                time.sleep(3)
            elif choice == "5":
                firstNum=input ("\nPlease enter first number : ")
                print "Answer is " ,sqr(firstNum)
                time.sleep(3)
            elif choice == "6":
                break
         except ValueError:
             print ("Oops!! that was not a valid number.  Try again....")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove print statement before the mainmenu(). Just call function.

```
 mainmenu() #just call function.
 choice = raw_input("Enter your correct number [1-7]: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by the line

```
print mainmenu()
```

Since the function mainmenu() does not return a value (hence the `None`).